# What NewSQL database supporting SQL, horizontal scaling, good read/write performance. Analytics / AI (Cassandra failed)

Tags: sql, nosql

We are looking for NewSQL database.

We were using ScyllaDB (Cassandra) which in ~ 10 days test just had fatal crash (all nodes are unresponsive to API, CSQL is working, one node after reset has lost data for > 5 days (100GB), after reset failed to rebuild).

This is the most tragic crash that any DB that we've tested had, so we are looking for something else.

In terms of data we're talking about 200-500TB per month, > 10 nodes.

~ 50k writes a second, ~ 200k reads a second.

We need something that:

- supports SQL (Cassandra was a huge headache during design stage, impossible to replace certain aspects of our MySQL database (which is fine, but we are testing new product that has much higher requirements)
- can scale horizontally well from 5-10-50 nodes + regional support (we have farms on in 8 main locations, they have to replicate fairly well, but clients from i.e. USA West won't access data in USA East)
- can support read/write scaling
- we do not use transactions as per se, but want to be able to where X = 'E' and Date > '2020'

Comment: Have you looked at MySQL NDB cluster? Cell phone carriers have similar goals but NDB != InnoDB so please research

Comment: I was looking at this, but I am not sure if this would support join where A.Id == B.ClientId. We do not have transactions, with simple SQL to retrieve entities where A = B, joins, limit etc. However we always search for last 100000, or where date < or >